# Camera is upside down OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, rotation

I'm having an issue with my camera being upside down in OpenGL.
If I render my objects without setting the camera Z rotation to 180 degrees, the objects get rendered upside down.
Maybe it has something to do with glm?

Here's how I'm setting up my matrices:

```
//Model Matrix:
mat4 modelMatrix;
modelMatrix = translate(modelMatrix, vec3(entity.getPosition().x, entity.getPosition().y, entity.getPosition().z));
modelMatrix = rotate(modelMatrix, (float) (entity.getRotation().x / 180 * PI), vec3(1, 0, 0));
modelMatrix = rotate(modelMatrix, (float) (entity.getRotation().y / 180 * PI), vec3(0, 1, 0));
modelMatrix = rotate(modelMatrix, (float) (entity.getRotation().z / 180 * PI), vec3(0, 0, 1));
modelMatrix = scale(modelMatrix, entity.getScale());
return modelMatrix;

//View Matrix:
mat4 viewMatrix;
viewMatrix = rotate(viewMatrix, (float)(camera.getRotation().x / 180 * PI), vec3(1, 0, 0));
viewMatrix = rotate(viewMatrix, (float)(camera.getRotation().y / 180 * PI), vec3(0, 1, 0));
viewMatrix = rotate(viewMatrix, (float)(camera.getRotation().z / 180 * PI), vec3(0, 0, 1));
viewMatrix = translate(viewMatrix, camera.getPosition() * vec3(-1, -1, -1));
return viewMatrix;

//Projection Matrix:
return glm::perspective(camera.getFieldOfView(), Display::getWindowAspectRatio(), camera.getNearPlane(), camera.getFarPlane());
```

And here's my draw method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < entityMap.size(); i++)
{
    map<GLuint, vector<Entity>>::iterator iterator(entityMap.begin());
    advance(iterator, i);

    vector<Entity> entityBatch = iterator->second;

    Model entityModel = entityBatch[0].getModel();

    mat4 *modelMatrices = new mat4[entityBatch.size()];

    for (int j = 0; j < entityBatch.size(); j++)
    {
        modelMatrices[j] = Maths::createModelMatrix(entityBatch[j]);
    }

    glBindVertexArray(iterator->first);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);

    GLuint vertexBufferObjectId;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObjectId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObjectId);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mat4) * entityBatch.size(), modelMatrices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(vec4), (GLvoid*)(0 * sizeof(vec4)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(vec4), (GLvoid*)(1 * sizeof(vec4)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(vec4), (GLvoid*)(2 * sizeof(vec4)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(vec4), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(vec4)));

    glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);

    #if ENABLE_INDEXING
    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, entityModel.getIndexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, entityBatch.size());
    #else
    glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, entityModel.getVertexCount(), entityBatch.size());
    #endif

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(4);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(5);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObjectId);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Without showing how you are drawing and how you setup your matrices, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: What are the values for the rotations? Does the same thing happen if you do not apply any of the rotations at all? I probably know what's going on, but it wouldn't explain why things flip upside down unless there are rotations involved.

Comment: I tried not applying the rotations and it didn't work.
By the way, just the camera gets flipped upside down. The world coordinates get reversed and objects appear to be upside down.

Answer (score 9):

The problem was with my projection matrix.

I forgot that glm works in radians and didn't convert the field of view from degrees to radians. Everything works fine now.

I have one more question.
Do you need to give the glm::perspect

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I had this issue when trying to emulate the camera view I got in Blender. Upon setting the FOV from 45 to 49.134 (for 35mm film), Y was flipped upside down. After all this time I've used 45 'degrees' as my FOV, I've actually been using 45 radians which wraps to approximately 58 degrees. Ha!